# swift sending json to php server

Tags: php, json, swift

I looked to many materials and used lots of way sending json data to php server. First I am creating order of singleORder and collecting it in arrayOfOrders :

```
func createOrderInArray(){

    var savedDataHourly: NSDictionary
    var savedDataTransfer:NSDictionary
    var savedDataReis: NSDictionary
    var singleOrderClass = Order()
    //localArrayOfOrder = []

    singleOrderClass.type_id = singleStructDataOfCar.typeID
    singleOrderClass.model_id = singleStructDataOfCar.modelID

    // loading hourly
    if Load.dictionary("ServiceByHours") != nil {
         savedDataHourly = Load.dictionary("ServiceByHours")
        println("loading hourly")
        singleOrderClass.hourly.addressOfRequest = savedDataHourly["ServiceByHoursAddressOFRequest"] as String
        singleOrderClass.hourly.addressOfDelivery = savedDataHourly["ServiceByHoursAddressOfDelivery"] as String
        singleOrderClass.hourly.detailedText = savedDataHourly["ServiceByHoursDetailText"] as String
        singleOrderClass.hourly.startofWork = savedDataHourly["StartDate"] as String
        singleOrderClass.hourly.endOfWork = savedDataHourly["EndDate"] as String
        singleOrderClass.hourly.undefinedTime = savedDataHourly["undefinedTime"] as String

    }else{
        println("hourly is empty")
        singleOrderClass.hourly.addressOfRequest = ""
        singleOrderClass.hourly.addressOfDelivery = ""
        singleOrderClass.hourly.detailedText = ""
        singleOrderClass.hourly.startofWork = ""
        singleOrderClass.hourly.endOfWork = ""
        singleOrderClass.hourly.undefinedTime = ""
    }
    // loading transfer
    if Load.dictionary("ServiceByTransfer") != nil {
        savedDataTransfer = Load.dictionary("ServiceByTransfer")
        singleOrderClass.transfer.startofWork = savedDataTransfer["ServiceDataStartDate"] as String
        singleOrderClass.transfer.addressOfRequest = savedDataTransfer["ServiceDataAddressOfReq"] as String
        singleOrderClass.transfer.addressOfDelivery = savedDataTransfer["ServiceDataAddressOfDel"] as String
        singleOrderClass.transfer.detailedText = savedDataTransfer["ServiceDataDetailedText"] as String

    }else{
        singleOrderClass.transfer.startofWork = ""
        singleOrderClass.transfer.addressOfRequest = ""
        singleOrderClass.transfer.addressOfDelivery = ""
        singleOrderClass.transfer.detailedText = ""
    }
    // loading reis
    if Load.dictionary("ServiceByReis") != nil {
        savedDataReis = Load.dictionary("ServiceByReis")
        singleOrderClass.custom.startofWork = savedDataReis["ServiceDataStartDate"] as String
        singleOrderClass.custom.addressOfRequest = savedDataReis["ServiceDataAddressOfReq"] as String
        singleOrderClass.custom.addressOfDelivery = savedDataReis["ServiceDataAddressOfDel"] as String
        singleOrderClass.custom.detailedText = savedDataReis["ServiceDataDetailedText"] as String
        singleOrderClass.custom.priceProposed = savedDataReis["ServiceDataPrice"] as String
    }else{
        singleOrderClass.custom.startofWork = ""
        singleOrderClass.custom.addressOfRequest = ""
        singleOrderClass.custom.addressOfDelivery = ""
        singleOrderClass.custom.detailedText = ""
        singleOrderClass.custom.priceProposed = ""
    }

    // add this single order to array

    arrayOfOrders.append(singleOrderClass)

}
```

I am just collecting all orders in one array. The next step is to convert all data in array to Dictionary so I can Serialized it into json format:

```
func createJsonFromArrayToDict(orders: [Order])->[AnyObject]{

    //as Dictionary<String, String>
    var dictOfOrders: [AnyObject] = []
    var counter = 0

    for singleOrder in orders {
        counter = counter + 1
        println("COUNTER: \(counter)")

        var dicOfOrder = [
            "type_id": singleOrder.type_id,
            "model_id": singleOrder.model_id,
            "transfer": [
                "StartDate": singleOrder.transfer.startofWork,
                "StartPoint": singleOrder.transfer.addressOfRequest,
                "EndPoint": singleOrder.transfer.addressOfDelivery,
                "CommentText": singleOrder.transfer.detailedText
            ],
            "hourly": [
                "StartDate": singleOrder.hourly.startofWork,
                "EndDate": singleOrder.hourly.endOfWork,
                "StartPoint": singleOrder.hourly.addressOfRequest,
                "EndPoint": singleOrder.hourly.addressOfDelivery,
                "CommentText": singleOrder.hourly.detailedText,
                "Undefined_Time": singleOrder.hourly.undefinedTime
            ],
            "custom":[
                "StartDate": singleOrder.custom.startofWork,
                "StartPoint": singleOrder.custom.addressOfRequest,
                "EndPoint": singleOrder.custom.addressOfDelivery,
                "CommentText": singleOrder.custom.detailedText,
                "customPrice": singleOrder.custom.priceProposed
            ],
            "device_name": "ios_device"
        ]
        // check if it is not the same order as previous (need to include this in future)
        dictOfOrders.append(dicOfOrder)

    }

    return dictOfOrders
}
```

Now I am sending this JSON to server using this function:

```
func sendJsonToServer(OrderList: AnyObject){
var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "osc.kz/ru/test")!)

    var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    var err: NSError?
if let serializedData = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(OrderList, options: nil, error: &err){
    request.HTTPBody = serializedData
    println(request.HTTPBody)
    }

    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")


    var task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
        println("Response: \(response)")
        var strData = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        println("Body: \(strData)")
        var err: NSError?
        var json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableLeaves, error: &err) as NSArray
        // var json = noWrappedJson!
        // Did the JSONObjectWithData constructor return an error? If so, log the error to the console
        if(err != nil) {
            println(err!.localizedDescription)
            let jsonStr = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            println("Error could not parse JSON: '\(jsonStr)'")
        }
        else {
            // The JSONObjectWithData constructor didn't return an error. But, we should still
            // check and make sure that json has a value using optional binding.
            for singleCode in json {
                if let parseJSON = singleCode as? NSDictionary {
                    // Okay, the parsedJSON is here, let's get the value for 'success' out of it
                    var success = parseJSON["code"] as? String
                    println("Succes: \(success)")
                }
                else {
                    // Woa, okay the json object was nil, something went worng. Maybe the server isn't running?
                    let jsonStr = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                    println("Error could not parse JSON: \(jsonStr)")
                }
            }
        }

    })

    task.resume()
}
```

However, My server is getting empty array []. I couldnt figure out why am I sending empty value. Before sending request I printed request.httpbody. It has a value, but the server get [] . Any suggestion is appreciated!

The server side is on PHP:

```
<?php
 if ($_REQUEST)
{   $_ARR = $_REQUEST;
$OrderList = $_ARR['OrderList'];
foreach($OrderList as $order){
 $auto_type_id = $order['type_id'];


$auto_model_id = $order['model_id'];



$device_name = $order['device_name'];
   $commentText = $order['commentText'];


 $transfer = '';
   $hourly = '';
   $custom = '';
   if (!empty($order['transfer'])) {
    $transfer = $order['transfer'];
    $db->query("insert into table_test_android set json_text = 'transfer' ");
    $db->query("insert into table_test_android set json_text = 'type:".$auto_type_id.",model_id:".$auto_model_id.",device:".$device_name."' ");
   }
   if (!empty($order['hourly'])) {
    $hourly = $order['hourly'];
    $db->query("insert into table_test_android set json_text = 'hourly' ");
    $db->query("insert into table_test_android set json_text = 'type:".$auto_type_id.",model_id:".$auto_model_id.",device:".$device_name."' ");
   }
   if (!empty($order['custom'])) {
    $custom = $order['custom'];
    $db->query("insert into table_test_android set json_text = 'custom' ");
    $db->query("insert into table_test_android set json_text = 'type:".$auto_type_id.",model_id:".$auto_model_id.",device:".$device_name."' ");
   }

  }

  $db->query("insert into table_test_android set json_text = '".json_encode($_ARR)."'");
  $code_my = mt_rand(100000, 999999);
  $code[] = array('code'=>(string)$code_my);echo json_encode($code);
 }
```

Comment: Please show how you are attempting to retrieve the data on your server, eg the php

Comment: I added the server side

Comment: Incidentally, this line is redundant and probably a bad idea: `$_ARR = $_REQUEST`. Redundant, because you copy the variable, access one element of it, and then discard it. Probably a bad idea, because the `$_UPPERCASE` format makes it look like a reserved superglobal, but actually it's just a normal local variable, so it's misleading to future readers of the code (e.g. you in a few months time debugging it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are sending json data, phps superglobals will not be populated - to access the json you need to access the raw input stream:

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
//echo $json shoulkd show the json string

$array = json_decode($json, true);
// var_dump($arr) should show the array structure

$OrderList = $array['OrderList'];
//provided your json is structured correctly everything else should work from here on
```

EDIT You probably have a number of other problems, for a start your sql is wrong - INSERT syntax looks like `'INSTERT into tablename (colname, anothercolname) VALUES (val,val);'` Whereas you have a weird inset/update mashup, but this is beyond the scope of this question (how to send json data to server)

Comment: @YestayMuratov Well, if your request body has the correct data in it, then yes i presume client side is fine - i am not experienced enough in swift (or objective-c) to answer that fully. Did you try the php i suggested?

Answer (score 0):

Though the above answer works but as much as you can stay away from "php://input" the better for you. If you want to send an array of data [String : Any] to a php API i recommend doing the following:

1. Populate the Array [String : Any].
2. Convert the array to Data using JSONSerialization:

   JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: array, options: [])
3. Create a URLRequest and set method to POST:

   var request = URLRequest(url: url)
4. Create a string variable parameter example:

   let parameter = "postData=" + data.base64EncodedString() //(data variable is from step 2)
5. In the URLRequest variable (request), populate the httpBody, example:

   request.httpBody = parameter.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
6. Send the request using URLSession.shared.dataTask ...

in PHP, catch the post using $_POST["postData"], then decode the value of the post parameter using base64_decode which gives you a string representation of the json, after that you can use json_decode() to transform it into an associated array, see below:

```
$content = $_POST["postData"];
$decodedContent = base64_decode($content);
$json = json_decode($decodedContent, true);
```